# Login in Extjs using java spring Bean

Tags: ajax, spring, extjs, response, javabeans

I am trying to authenticate a user's username and password using an Ajax call.The parameters are passed to java bean and it should return a success or a failure message string to the caller but it shows a Servlet service error.The code is as follows:

```
  package com.eits.portal.controller;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import javax.servlet.ServletException;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
  import net.sf.json.JSONObject;
  import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
  import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController;

  import com.eits.portal.service.OrgTreeService;


public class UserLoginController  extends MultiActionController {
OrgTreeService orgTreeService;

ModelAndView mv;
public String getLoginStatus(HttpServletRequest paramHttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse paramHttpServletResponse)
        throws Exception{
    //paramHttpServletResponse.setContentType("application/json");

    String userId = paramHttpServletRequest.getParameter("user");
    String password = paramHttpServletRequest.getParameter("password");
    String s="";
      System.out.println("---node"+userId);
      System.out.println("---node"+password);
      String us="admin";
      String pass="admin";



      if(userId.equals(us)&& password.equals(pass)){
                 s="success";
          System.out.println("success ");
      }else{
          s="failure";

          System.out.println("unsuccessful");
      }

      return s;
}
 public void setOrgTreeService(OrgTreeService paramOrgTreeService)
  {
     this.orgTreeService = paramOrgTreeService;
  }

 }
```

The code is pretty simple and it does print success on passing the right username and password in the IDE console , but the same string is not passing to the caller function for the front end.Here is a snapshot of the error I am getting :-

```
  http://gyazo.com/12b386a9e586fc0ee5514800c9822071
```

Is this a right way to pass the success to the caller method , or should i pass an object instead of the string?

Comment: It is not an error but an URL... what is the exact error you are getting in your console...?

Comment: @Nomesh Desilva It shows the following error 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you are getting a 404 (Not Found) then you should check that you are calling the correct URL and that your servlet request mapping configuration is specified correctly, e.g. via @RequestMapping annotation if using Spring.

Then, assuming you are making a request similar to below, you can return a Json string from your controller method that will be returned in the response and can be decoded into an object, assuming you may want to pass back more details than simply "success" or "failure".

```js
Ext.Ajax.request({
  url: '/someUrl',
  params: {
    user: 'username',
    password: 'password'
  },
  callback: function(options, success, response) {
    if (success) {
      var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
      ....
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes the URL is correct, The parameters reach the url correctly and here is how i have done my servlet request mapping : http://gyazo.com/d5528521db30be00e1872e3cfc4853f1